# Check if max per category Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a column that returns 1 for the Max Rev number. My table looks like this:

```
Serial#   Enrollment#    Rev#
1234      0001           0
1234      0001           1
2225      0002           0
9999      0003           0
9999      0003           1
9999      0003           2
9999      0004           0
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
Serial#   Enrollment#    Rev#   MaxRev
1234      0001           0      0
1234      0001           1      1
2225      0002           0      1
9999      0003           0      0
9999      0003           1      0
9999      0003           2      1
9999      0004           0      1
```

Here is what I tried:

```
MaxRev = IF(CVA[Rev#] = CALCULATE(MAX([Rev#]),CVA[Enrollment#] = EARLIER(CVA[Enrollment#])),1,0)
```

But it is not working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ALLEXCEPT` to remove the filter context on all columns except [Enrollment#]. Note, because of `CALCULATE` (context transition), this may be slow if the table is large (millions of rows).

```
MaxRev = IF(CVA[Rev#] = CALCULATE(MAX(CVA[Rev#]), ALLEXCEPT(CVA, CVA[Enrollment#])), 1, 0)
```